# Passing case objects in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following definitions:

```
sealed trait MyTrait
case object One extends MyTrait
case object Two extends MyTrait

object Test extends (MyTrait => MyTraitReturnVal) {

  def apply(myTrait: MyTrait) = { ... }

  def myMethod(myTrait: MyTrait) = {
  ...
  }
}
```

When I call Test(One), it complains that it is expecting an interface instead of a concrete type. Any suggestions on how to get around this?

So calling:

```
Test(One)
```

Complains that it is expecting MyTrait and the actual parameter is One.type!

Comment: What is the exact error message, on what exact code line?

Comment: How do you implement the function you extend? (Or why is the `myMethod` is in the example code?)

Comment: Is it working if you add type hint, like: `Test(One: MyTrait)`? Are there other objects, classes named `One`?

Comment: Why is my question down voted? Whoever down voted it, can you give me the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inheriting Test object from Function1 class, so you need to implement 'apply' method instead of 'myMethod'. This code compiles and runs:

```
  sealed trait MyTrait
  case object One extends MyTrait
  case object Two extends MyTrait

  case class MyTraitReturnVal(my: MyTrait)

  object Test extends (MyTrait => MyTraitReturnVal) {
    def apply(myTrait: MyTrait) =
      new MyTraitReturnVal(myTrait)
  }

  println(Test(One))
  println(Test(Two))
```

Comment: I do have an apply. But that is not the problem.

Comment: I have the sealed traits and the case objects inside a default package object. Is that probably the reason why I get a compile error?

Comment: No, it should not. It's hard to say what exactly is wrong without 'real' code. Can you create gist with full code and split it to files

Comment: I guess I figured out the problem. It is considering MyTraitReturnVal to be a new type in the extends clause and the import for it is not recognized.